# Angular2 in Offline Environment with asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm was developing a pilot project in asp.net MVC5 with AngularJS 1.5, environment but if same I want to develop with Angular2 can I develop it an environment where I can manually attach Required JS files to the system.

If any tutorial link, I can refer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: See [Angular Developer Guide - QuickStart](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/lN3xGdFXVnhjZalrGg7S?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes yo can do that just specify your code in budleConifg and render it in your view

```
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
            {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Angular").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/yourscriptsrc1",
                           "~/Scripts/yourscriptsrc2"
)); 
    }
```

and in the view just call

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
```

since these are basic files you gonna use in evry part of app mostly just call this in _Layout page of your app

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rahul s r, but i'm following this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181888/Angular-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-Part, were i npm is required to download the required JS which i want to do manually as you suggested in bundle config or direct script link in head section

Comment: @MukeshGupta if you are going to use offline Envirnoment why are you trying to add the npm directory ? you dont have to add that you can skip that ...(be sure you are adding the required files manually)  the npm tpes and packag.json files can be skiped in this instance